# AttributeError with my code about data attributes

Tags: python, numpy, probability

I decided to simulate a function in a tutorial and I wonder why I am getting the error "AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'logpdf'"

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

pL = stats.norm(loc=-1, scale=1).rvs(5)
pR = stats.norm(loc=1, scale=1).rvs(5)
PT = pL.logpdf(pL) - pL.logpdf(pR)
```

Comment: How are we supposed to help?  With an attribute error like this either the class of `pL` is wrong (you assigned the wrong value to it), or attribute/method name is wrong.  `logpdf` is NOT a numpy array method.  I don't know what kind of object has such a method.  We know nothing about the tutorial (and you shouldn't expect us to look it up).

Answer (score 0):

NumPy has decided not to clear the FP exception after calling fmod.
https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/17547#issuecomment-714310892